# Doing model selection in python / scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statsmodels

During model selection, sometimes the likelihood-ratio test, or analysis using BIC (Bayesian Information Criterion) are often necessary. While I could definitely do it by hand, I was wondering, is there any scipy functions that are designed to do this?

I am asking this question because I think there should be a way to do this type of analysis, or, at least a function to get the likelihood value.

PS: I am not thinking about fitting a single distribution, instead, I am thinking about looking at some 1D data that changes with time (i.e. the model prediction changes with time).

Any help would be appreciated!

Example for this question:

I have some data that looks like this.
[image: Dummy data]

And now, I have two models - one with four parameters, another model nested in it with two parameters (fixing the other two).

I want to perform BIC / likelihood-ratio test to see, whether the two free parameters will make a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

In statsmodels you can perform likelihood ratio and Wald tests. Different information criteria are also available for all of the models. There are a few other model selection techniques, but I'm going to need to know a little bit more about what you're doing to give specific answers. Meanwhile, our documentation should help http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I have not updated my thread so it includes an example. I did look into statsmodels, but only find the tests with linear regressions (under OLS), instead of general models (like the example I gave in the question). Could you please help? Really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you write the actual models or provide the code that you're using to fit them? It's still not clear (to me) what you mean by your parameters. Are these coefficients in a linear regression model, some kind of time-series model, or something else?